# Discord JS: How do I delete all messages the bot has sent in DM's?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot delete all DM's from a user ID. How would I get about doing this?
I have tried using the DMchannel function but I am struggling. The following code is what I have tried

```
const dmCount = client.users.get("508625644792446986").dmChannel
var fetched =  dmCount.fetchMessages({limit: 99});
dmCount.bulkDelete(fetched)
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here, any suggestions on how to fix this?
The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMessages' of null
```

Comment: AFAIK `dmCount.fetchMessages` returns a promise - it's an async function. You have to either await it or add `.then()` and move your bulkDelete call to the callback.

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk This didn't work, the error I'm getting is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMessages' of null

Comment: If you are using v12 of the API, use `dmCount.messages.fetch` instead of `dmCount.fetchMessages`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not for sure, but I think a user's direct message guild/channel will always = "null" because it's not in a server. You could do a command that only activates when the channel/guild = "null". But I don't think you can delete messages that were direct messaged sadly (at least with current Discord.js).